# How to compare two tables and show every difference

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, compare

I got two tables with each 1 column. I want to compare those column and see if they are the same. The two tables look something like this:

Table one:

```
-----
| 1 |
-----
| 2 |
-----
| 3 |
-----
| 4 |    
-----
| 5 |
-----
| 6 |
-----
| 7 |
-----
| 8 |
-----
| 9 |
-----
```

Table two:

```
----- <-- missing `1` in table 
| 2 |
----- <-- missing `3` in table 
| 4 |    
-----
| 5 |
-----
| 5.5 | <-- extra `5.5` in table 
-----
| 6 |
-----
| 8 | <-- this one isnt the same as the `7` in table one
-----
| 7 | <-- this one isnt the same as the `9` in table one
-----
| 9 |
-----
```

And the SQL query should return a table like this:

```
-----------------
| Table1| Table2|
----- -----------
| 1     |       |
----- -----------
| 3     |       |
-----------------
|       | 5.5   |
-----------------
| 7     | 8     |
-----------------
| 8     | 7     |
-----------------
```

So if one value is only in 1 of those tables, it needs to be `selected`. Also if in table two the string after the previous string is not the same as the string after the previous string in table one, it needs to be `selected`

Comment: Do you mean 2 tables in one database

Comment: SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 t1
       FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 t2
                    ON t1.col = t2.col
WHERE  t1.col IS NULL
        OR t2.col IS NULL
```

If your DBMS does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN` then

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 t1
       LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
                    ON t1.col = t2.col
WHERE  t2.col IS NULL
Union all
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 t1
       Right JOIN Table2 t2
                    ON t1.col = t2.col
WHERE  t1.col IS NULL
```

Comment: Answering these ___Do it all for me question___ just encourages more such questions

Comment: @RiggsFolly - But thats a interesting question at least to me ;)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I do not understand your comment, it means that you should not give the specific answer but explain without giving the example?

Comment: @JotaPardo - it means OP did not made any attempt to solve your own problem. We are not supposed to encourage such questions by writing answers

Comment: @Prdp Thanks for the help, when I run ur code, it doenst find any differences in the two tables, while there definitely are differences between those two tables.

Comment: @wouterdejong - You are using `Mysql` or `Sql Server`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Now I understand. So for us to help the OP better we should encourage them to make first attempts and give us their results, right? How could he prove that he tested? with queries made?

Comment: @Prdp to be honest, i dont know, im guessing MYSQL, but im using sql in visual studio  with a server connection. this is standing at my root: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL` and this is my SQL server object explorer: http://imgur.com/a/juMBB

Comment: @wouterdejong - Oh boy that is `SQL SERVER`

Comment: @Prdp Thanks, now I know :)

Comment: @Prdp Nevermind, I made a mistake myself. Thank a lot for helping me

Comment: @Prdp Tho it doenst filter the `7` and `8` in my example

Answer (score 1):

Full outer join is what you need

```
select *
from mytable1 a1
full outer join mytable2 a2
on a1.mycolumn = a2.mycolumn
```

to only show the ones where one is missing, add:

```
where a1.mycolumn is null
or a2.mycolumn is null
```

Comment: Answering these ___Do it all for me question___ just encourages more such questions

Comment: @RiggsFolly I do not understand your comment, it means that you should not give the specific answer but explain without giving the example?